# facing issue with floating left and right properties

Tags: html, css

I have a page that needs divs to be centered and another background divs to be on the most left with 100% width i've put an inner div inside the big one but now i want to align text vertically for both side:
i have 4 images to be set on a line if i put all of them floating right i'll have white space left and vice versa
This is my code:

```
<div class="programsAndEvents">
        <div class="centerDiv">
            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 16</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 17</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 18</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 19</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.programsAndEvents {
    background-color: #F7E4D3;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
}

.program {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto;
    border-right:1px solid;
}

.btnDetails {
    background-color:  #FBC563;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    margin:10 50;
}

.day {
    margin-left:35%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family: courier;
}

hr {
    width:10%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius:3px ;
    background-color: gray;
}

.prog {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin :10 30;
}
```

And if someone can please suggest another way to center the text inside the div i will much appreciate it.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

you used to `.prog` class `margin : 10 30;` is invalid **used** to `px` or `em` or `%`

**Try to  this css**

```
          .prog {
              margin :10 30; // remove this line 
            }
            .program{
              text-align:center; // add this line
            }

            .day {
                margin-left:35%;  //remove this line
            }
        .program {
            border-right:1px solid; // remove this line
        }
        .program + .program {
            border-left:1px solid; // add line line and this css
        }
    .btnDetails{
      margin:10 50; // remove this line
    }
.centerDiv{
  margin: 0 auto; // add this line 
  text-align: center;  // add this line 
  font-size: 0;  // add this line 
}
.program{
  font-size:12px; // add this line 
}
```

=======================

**Demo**

```css
.programsAndEvents {
    background-color: #F7E4D3;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
}

.program {
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto;
    
    text-align:center;
}
.program + .program {
border-left:1px solid;
}

.btnDetails {
    background-color:  #FBC563;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    
}

.day {

    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family: courier;
}
.centerDiv{
  margin: 0 auto;  
  text-align: center;    
  font-size: 0;  
}
.program{
  font-size:12px;  
}
hr {
    width:10%;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius:3px ;
    background-color: gray;
}

.prog {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="programsAndEvents">
        <div class="centerDiv">
            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 16</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 17</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 18</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>

            <div class="program">
                <span class="day">JUL 19</span>
                <hr>
                <p class ="prog">"Mathew"</p>
                <button class="btnDetails">DETAILS</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: eventhough i don't understand any of these changed it worked perfectly Thank youu

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of .program div and set last child of program div border

```html
.program {
    width: 24.5%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto;
    border-right:1px solid;
}
.program:last-child {
   border:none;
}
```